RFID Reader gives only last 8 digits in decimal instead all 10 in HEX
I have two readers, an expesive reference one and the cheap ones that are being put into our devices.
The expensive one reads the RFID UIDs at 10HEX digits (40 bits) and the results are as I expect them to be.
The cheap ones all just read the last 8 HEX digits, but as decimals. (so the last 32 bits it seems)
Here examples of 3 RFID tag reads:
Expensive Elatec reader tells me UID is: 0113E85D03 (HEX)
Cheap Amazon reader: 0333995267
If I convert the latter to HEX it is: 13E85D03 which is missing the two leading digits.
Here other rfid Chip examples:
Example 2
Expensive Elatec reader tells me UID is: AA36C1F513 (HEX)
Cheap Amazon reader: 0918680851 -> 36C1F513
Example 3
Expensive Elatec reader tells me UID is: AA0707225F (HEX)
Cheap Amazon reader: 0117908063 -> 707225F (1 digit shorter than previous conversions, Im guessing that the website I use to convert is omitting leading 0s
I can just omit the first two digits and code around them missing, but this is not a sustainable solution. Any Idea why the amazon reader would omitt the first 8 bits, or am I looking at a conversion issue?
